# SQL subtracting results of 2 select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries that work perfectly fine in isolation:

```
SELECT patient.patient_id, sum(cost)
FROM patient, appointment 
WHERE patient.patient_id = appointment.patient_id 
GROUP BY patient.patient_id
```

---

```
SELECT sum(payment_amount)
FROM patient, payment
WHERE patient.patient_id = payment.patient_id
GROUP BY patient.patient_id
```

What I would like to know is how I might subtract the results of the second query from the first to create a current_balance field in my `patient` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend an approach like this:

```
select patient_id, sum(cost) as cost, sum(payment) as payment,
       sum(cost) - sum(payment) as balance
from ((select a.patient_id, cost as cost, 0 as payment
       from appointment a
      ) union all
      (select p.patient_id, 0 as cost, payment
       from payment p
      )
     ) ap
group by patient_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Roll up both quires into one and then deduct the `SUM`s.

```
SELECT pat.patient_id, SUM(cost) SUMCOST, SUM(payment_amount) SUMpayment_amount, SUM(cost) - SUM(payment_amount) current_balance 
FROM patient pat
INNER JOIN payment pay ON pat.patient_id = pay.patient_id 
INNER JOIN appointment app ON pat.patient_id = app.patient_id
GROUP BY pat.patient_id
```

Comment: I understand the answer but not the upvote.  (1) This filters out patients who do not have both costs and payments.  (2) This overcounts both payments and costs for patients who have more than one of either.  And, as a minor note, it does not even include the `patient_id` on each row.